# Angular 2 - Creates multiple rectangle in Google maps and refresh the data position

Tags: angular, google-maps

In **Angular 2** i have a Google maps with help of **[Angular Maps](https://angular-maps.com/)**. This maps has to a option to create some rectangles. The code is

```
mapReady(map: any) {
    this.draw = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
        ]
      },
      rectangleOptions: {
        editable: true,
        draggable: true
      }
    }),
      this.map = map;
    this.draw.setMap(map);
  }
```

I can create rectangle. I want to get this rectangle position data. I try to something like this.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(this.draw, 'overlaycomplete', function (polygon) {
      console.log(polygon.overlay.getBounds()
 });
```

But return only first position data, ignores when i drag to a new position in the map. Also too I want to remove previous rectangle when i create a some new.

So the questions:

1. How can i remove the previous rectangle when i create new one?
2. How can i update (get new position coords) the rectangle data positon when i create a new / move a existed rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#rectangle_add), there is a proper way of creating a rectangle and specifying events. Since you are using a 3rd party library/package, the features or their own documentation can be quite limited. Since you are using Angular, there is actually a way to make use of the official documentation.

You can refer to the sample code I made here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rectangle-position-63886966

> **Note**: if you get a `google is not defined` error, that is just due to stackblitz, and will disappear if you modify (i.e. add a space) anywhere (i.e. the .ts files). Also replace the API key placeholder with your own inside the `index.html` file to make it run properly.

index.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
<my-app>loading</my-app>
```

style.css

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.map {
  height:100%;
}
```

mapcomponent.html

```
<div #map class="map"></div>
```

mapcomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
declare const google: any;
// This example adds a user-editable rectangle to the map.
// When the user changes the bounds of the rectangle,
// an info window pops up displaying the new bounds.
var rectangle;
var infoWindow;
@Component({
  selector: 'my-maps',
  templateUrl: './simple-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simple-map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('map', { static: true }) mapElement: any;
  map: any; 
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const mapProperties = { 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5452,-78.5389), 
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapProperties);

   const bounds = {
    north: 44.599,
    south: 44.49,
    east: -78.443,
    west: -78.649
  }; // Define the rectangle and set its editable property to true.

  rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: bounds,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true
  }); 
  rectangle.setMap(this.map); // Add an event listener on the rectangle.

  rectangle.addListener("bounds_changed", this.showNewRect); // Define an info window on the map.

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  }
  /** Show the new coordinates for the rectangle in an info window. */

  showNewRect() {
  const ne = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast();
  const sw = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest();
  const contentString =
    "<b>Rectangle moved.</b><br>" +
    "New north-east corner: " +
    ne.lat() +
    ", " +
    ne.lng() +
    "<br>" +
    "New south-west corner: " +
    sw.lat() +
    ", " +
    sw.lng(); // Set the info window's content and position.

  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(ne);
  infoWindow.open(this.map);
}
  
}
```